# 3D geometry arithmetic helper

Tags: math, symbolic-algebra, geometry

As a computer graphics programmer, I often have to deal with complex cases of solid geometry.
To resolve these cases, I need to find the formula expressing the value that I need depending on my variables (involving trigonometry and all that crazy stuff).
I can do this by hand, but that's not what I'm the most eased at, so it's quite long and prone to errors.

Do you know some software (free or paid, that's not an issue) that could help me on this?

I'm looking for something similar to GeoGebra, in which I could setup the space with an interactive visual feedback, symbolic computation and everything.
The only additional feature I need is the ability to mark a variable as unknown, in a way that it still appears on the computed symbolic results.
My goal is clear : take the final formula to use it in my programs.

I use Windows and Linux on a daily basis, so if it runs on one of them, it's fine.

Comment: I usually end up doing stuff like this with pen and paper, and some right triangles. Trigonometry is not crazy at all.

Comment: @DeerHunter Well, when it comes to solid geometry, it goes beyond my confidence level.  
And besides that, don't you think that such an app **should** exist?

Comment: Do you care about operating system? How about pricing?

Comment: @NickWilde If it runs on Windows or Linux, it's fine for me. And I don't care about pricing, I can afford a professional tool if there's need for it.